# Igros K'naos Regarding Rambam

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rambam

Where could I find the Igros K'naos regarding Rambam's works for free online? In particular I am looking for a quote from Radak about the aggados there. A screenshot of that page would suffice.

Comment: _Igerot Qena'ot_ is [part III of the Leipzig 1859 edition of _Qovetz Teshuvot ha-Rambam_](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43026&pgnum=254)

Comment: @TamirEvan thank you very much. Why not make that comment an answer?

Comment: Yowzers. Major vitriol against Rashba and co on that first page. Who actually wrote that? And do we know anything about the second student of the Rashba mentioned there David ben Shaul? He is given a mention in the Artscroll Rishonim book, but no personal info.

Comment: If you prefer text, Sefaria OCRed that volume. The naming for the letters hasn't been done yet, but it's here: http://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam.13

Comment: @Bachrach44 excellent! text is (almost) always better than non-text. If you want you can convert that from a comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text from the 1859 Leipzig edition:
http://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam,_Iggeret_Kanaut

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @TamirEvan the Igros K'naos are part of the 1859 Leipzig ed. of Kovetz T'shuvos HaRambam. The quote from Radak can be found [on page 3b there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43026&st=&pgnum=259&hilite=).