# Leaving a mate behind in egypt

Tags: marriage, divorce, yetziat-mitzrayim

Did any husbands leave behind wives, or any wives leave behind husbands in Egypt during the Exodus? If so did this qualify a divorce of sorts?

Comment: What do you mean, leave them behind? I'm pretty sure all of B'nei Yisrael left.

Comment: @Scimonster A bunch of them died before leaving, but I don't know if that's really what the OP is really asking about

Comment: @Scimonster I thought only a fifth left?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull That seems to be [just a Midrash](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351) the pashtanim strictly disagree with such a reading.

Answer (score 6):

[Rashi in Beshalach on "chamushim"](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9874/jewish/Chapter-13.htm#v=18&showrashi=true) states that all those left behind died during the three days of darkness. Every member of Bnai Yisrael who survived left in the Exodus. Thus, if a husband or wife was left behind, the person who left was a widow or widower.