# Does HaShem still do miracles in exile?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mesorah-tradition

Are there any sources that HaShem still performs 'open miracles' even during the exile?

Comment: What is your criteria for an 'open miracle'?

Comment: Perhaps consider clarifying which sort of sources you are looking for. E.g. does evidence from Aggada count?

Comment: how about jewish survival which is likened to a sheep among 70 wolves

Comment: @HaLeiVi open miracles ala Passover, hidden ala Purim

Answer (score 2):

Example of a miracle during the exile

[Boba metiya 59b](http://halakhah.com/babamezia/babamezia_59.html)

> On that day R. Eliezer brought forward every imaginable argument,3  but they did not accept them. Said he to them: 'If thehalachah agrees with me, let this carob-tree prove it!' Thereupon the carob-tree was torn a hundred cubits out of its place — others affirm, four hundred cubits. 'No proof can be brought from a carob-tree,' they retorted. Again he said to them: 'If the halachah agrees with me, let the stream of water prove it!' Whereupon the stream of water flowed backwards — 'No proof can be brought from a stream of water,' they rejoined. Again he urged: 'If the halachah agrees with me, let the walls of the schoolhouse prove it,' whereupon the walls inclined to fall. But R. Joshua rebuked them, saying: 'When scholars are engaged in a halachic dispute, what have ye to interfere?' Hence they did not fall, in honour of R. Joshua, nor did they resume the upright, in honour of R. Eliezer; and they are still standing thus inclined. Again he said to them: 'If thehalachah agrees with me, let it be proved from Heaven!' Whereupon a Heavenly Voice cried out: 'Why do ye dispute with R. Eliezer, seeing that in all matters the halachah agrees with him!' But R. Joshua arose and exclaimed: 'It is not in heaven.'4  What did he mean by this? — Said R. Jeremiah: That the Torah had already been given at Mount Sinai; we pay no attention to a Heavenly Voice, because Thou hast long since written in the Torah at Mount Sinai, After the majority must one incline.5
>   R. Nathan met Elijah6  and asked him: What did the Holy One, Blessed be He, do in that hour? — He laughed [with joy], he replied, saying, 'My sons have defeated Me, My sons have defeated Me.'

Comment: There is no proof that any aggadic story is meant historically. See the Rambam, intro to his commentary to the misnayos of pereq Cheileq, shortly before his list of 13 articles of faith.

Comment: @MichaBerger Walls of a building seem to be somthing very concret

Comment: There is a long litany of rishonim and acharonim who tell you that aggadic stories are told for their lessons, and historical truth was not a factor in deciding whether or not to repeat them.

Aside from the aforementioned Rambam, others who dismiss the idea that every aggadic story is historical include: R’ Saadia Gaon, R’ Avraham ben haRambam, the Maharsha, the Maharal, the Vilna Gaon, R’ Hirsch, R’ Yisrael Salanter, etc…

(RSR Hirsch's position <http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/faxes/hirschAgadaEnglish.pdf>. And R' Yisrael Salanter's <http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/faxes/rysAgadaEnglish.pdf>.)

Comment: @MichaBerger see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351?s=7|0.0361#53351

Comment: Thank you. Although I used a more subtle phrasing than found there. There is pro historicity, con, and chazal simply did not care one way or the other. In any case, it could well be that the issue being asked, if overt miracles could happen after the fall pf the BHMQ os itself one of the factors in the dispute about historicity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fusing of two pieces of wood into 1 in Yechezqel (haftarah for Vayigash) occurs in Galus Bavel (the Babylonian Exile). But then, the 10 plagues and the crossing of the Red See also occurred in Exile.

Yonah's experience with the fish and his overnight growing plant were outside Israel, but not during a time of exile.

Megillah 14a discusses whether Hallel is said on miracles that occur when in exile. Does that imply that there have been revealed miracles about which to ask the question? Depends partly on what you mean by "revealed miracle" -- does the military victory of Chanukah qualify? I realize it's in Israel, but if you consider that much violation of the norm to be a hidden miracle, we see the question of miracles and Hallel need not refer to revealed ones.

Comment: Also the miracles in the BHMQ ended with Shimon haTzadiw's passing. End of the Great Assembly, . Well before the exile, befpre Chanukah even. No more red wool tirning white on Yom Kippur, people ran put pf room, the showbread didn't stay fresh, etc... Perhaps the end of miracles was concurrent with the end of prophecy?