# Adducing Gezerah Shavah (גזירה שוה), list of Gezerah Shavah (גזירה שוה) words

Tags: midrash, parashat-vayeishev, hermeneutics

In Genesis [37:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0137.htm) we read

> Then a **man** found him, and behold, he was straying in the field, and
>   the **man** asked him, saying, "What are you looking for?"
>
> טווַיִּמְצָאֵ֣הוּ **אִ֔ישׁ** וְהִנֵּ֥ה תֹעֶ֖ה בַּשָּׂדֶ֑ה
>   וַיִּשְׁאָלֵ֧הוּ **הָאִ֛ישׁ** לֵאמֹ֖ר מַה־תְּבַקֵּֽשׁ

Rashi states [here](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/torahreading.asp?tdate=11/30/2015) as interpretation

> Then a man found him: This is [the angel] Gabriel, as it is said: “And
>   the man Gabriel” (Dan. 9:21). [From Tanchuma Vayeshev 2]

My [siddur](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&P_ID=1009) states on p.77 in the comments on the Baraita of Rabbi Yishmael, second principle of Torah interpretation, "similarity of words" (גזירה שוה)

> "A Gezerah Shavah (גזירה שוה) cannot be original, it must be passed
>   down from master to disciple, originating with Moshe to whom G'd
>   taught it at Mount Sinai"

In this particular case man means angel Gabriel. In other cases man (obviously?) does not mean angel Gabriel. So I have a couple of questions about this.

1. Is the Gen 27:15 specific man/ish interpretation an example of Gezerah Shavah (or maybe aggadah as a comment suggests)? How would one figure that out?
2. Was each specific case (word+context) of applying Gezerah Shavah passed down by Moshe, or did he give rules when/if to apply the rule based on other contextual clues?
3. Is there a listing of words that are used for Gezerah Shavah with the specific contexts they are to be used?

Comment: IIRC not everyone had the same list --- some authorities had words/examples on their lists that weren't accepted by others and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think that's a Gezera Shava being used there. There's no legal exegesis. It's agadda which is more flexible.

Comment: I think you should [edit] this question to be either about the nature of the particular *derasha* employed in this Rashi (Q1) or about *gezeirot shava* in general (Q2 and Q3) without any reference to Vayeishev necessary. The two together is confusing.

Comment: Regarding whether the Midrashim were handed down from Sinai, [the Geonim and most of the Rishonim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53351/8775), hold that they were not matters of tradition. Significantly, according to Rambam (shoresh sheni of SHM), even the halakhic derashot were not transmitted from Sinai.

Comment: Re #2, see #לד in [יד מלאכי](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ItCAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA5&ots=iA_jtgCNdY&dq=%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false). He cites the _Nimukei Yosef_ and others to say that there are actually instances of _g'zera shava_ which are exegetical and those which weren't (perhaps eisegetical?).

Comment: @Daniel can you split Q3 off as a separate (new) question?