# Why "לא ידענו מה היה לו" if they saw his bier?

Tags: midrash, rashi, maseches-shabbos, parashat-ki-tisa

My kid asked:

[*Ki Sisa* 32:1](http://www.chabad.org/9893#showrashi=true&v=1) says that, when *Moshe* didn't return from Mount Sinai when the people expected him to, they said "this man *Moshe* who brought us up out of the land of Egypt, we don't know what has become of him". *Rashi* comments that "this" means that they saw *Moshe*: specifically, [as *Shabas* 89 *amud* 1 makes more explicit,] that the *satan* showed them *Moshe*'s corpse being borne.

Why, then, did they say "we don't know what has become of him"? They (thought that they) knew what had become of him: he had died.

Comment: I posted one answer but hope others will post others.

Comment: Maybe they [didn't know the Midrash](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351).

Comment: @mevaqesh, I don't see how that helps. But if you can explain it, perhaps post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *Maharsha* (*Chidushe Agados* to *Shabas* 89) says that they had a slight doubt whether, perhaps, the image they saw of *Moshe* was actually an act of the *satan*'s.

Comment: Does Maharsha provide any support for his assertion? (eg. a linguistic oddity in the Midrash)

Comment: @DoubleAA, not there.

Answer (score 0):

The lashon of the passuk is odd, ki zeh Moshe ha'Ish. It should say ki zeh ha'Ish or ki Moshe eineno (or similar).

The implication is they were grappling with the idea of mortality, this man Moshe who represents mortals in the heavenly sphere.

Showing his bier may therefore be an indication that his corporeal self had been left behind in which case he could no longer lead them.

Comment: Interesting idea. Is it your own?

Answer (score 0):

[Shemos Rabbah 41:7](http://www.alonolam.com/t/f_01634_part_9.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) says that when satan showed them Moshe, Hur (the son of Caleb) arose and rebuked them:

> רבנן אמרי השטן מצא את ידיו אותה שעה, שהיה משה נראה תלוי בין השמים
>   והארץ והיו מראין אותו באצבע ואומר: כי זה משה האיש. **אותה שעה עמד
>   עליהם חור ואמר להם קציעי צואריא, אין אתם נזכרים מה נסים עשה לכם הקדוש
>   ברוך הוא**, מיד עמדו עליו והרגוהו.

According to my reading, it seems that after receiving this rebuke (and had killed him), they were still in doubt if what they saw was true or not, so they said "we don't know what has become of him".

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of this _midrash_ to your reading of the verses. Or is that your reading of this _midrash_ itself? How do you read that in it?

Comment: I believe it's relevant b/c IMO the midrash brings out Caleb's rebuke against the view of Moshe's death shown by satan and this would may suggest a remaining doubt of the people whether it really had happened or not, and consequently, the reason why they possibly said לא ידענו מה היה לו .