# How does Rashi know Yosef tells the Egyptians to circumcise themselves?

Tags: midrash, rashi, brit-milah, egypt, miketz

Genesis 41,55:

> וַתִּרְעַב֙ כָּל-אֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם וַיִּצְעַ֥ק הָעָ֛ם אֶל-פַּרְעֹ֖ה לַלָּ֑חֶם וַיֹּ֨אמֶר פַּרְעֹ֤ה לְכָל-מִצְרַ֨יִם֙ לְכ֣וּ אֶל-יוֹסֵ֔ף אֲשֶׁר-יֹאמַ֥ר לָכֶ֖ם תַּֽעֲשֽׂוּ: ‏
>
> And when all the land of Egypt was famished, the people cried to Pharaoh for bread; and Pharaoh said to all the Egyptians, Go to Joseph; what he said to you, do.

What did Yosef say to do? Rashi explained that he told the Egyptians to circumcise themselves.

[We know **why** Yosef tells them this.](/q/57816) But how does Rashi know this piece of information?

Comment: Rashi is quoting a Midrash, for a survey of rabbinic views on Midrash, such as whether it is necessarily based on a tradition, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351.

Answer (score 2):

Rashi is paraphrasing the ([Medrash Tanchuma Mikeitz](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11563&st=&pgnum=37&hilite=)), so that is his source.

Comment: Does the Midrash Tanchuma offer any explanation of its source, or any linguistic oddity which it is noting/resolving?

Comment: @DoubleAA,  No, it does not. It does indicate the conceptual oddity that it is addressing, though.

Comment: Could you [edit] that in, then?

Comment: @msh210, isn't that relevant to the other question? I'm not clear on the scope of this question, I guess. I thought it was just looking for the source. Should I go all out and discuss what is bothering Rashi here too? But that would just answer why he brings the Medrash, not where he got the idea from.

Comment: The other question is why _Yosef_ told them. This one is how we see that in the verses. (I think.) If the _midrash_ indicates what conceptual oddity makes it know _Yosef_ told them, that seems to be an answer here. If the _midrash_ indicates what conceptual oddity made _Yosef_ tell them, that seems to be an answer there. (I didn't check the _midrash_.)

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly Rashi knows this from [Midrash Bereishis Rabbah 99:5](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba1/91.htm).