# Will homosexuality be granted in Heaven for those who have been patient?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, homosexuality

I'm a woman who happened to be one of those who are born attracted to their same gender. But, I'm a strong follower of Judaism and I love Hashem a lot! Therefore I suppress all my desires for the sake of god, and I know for a fact that I will never allow myself to commit a sin involving homosexuality. Yet, everyone ends up loving someone, and I'm not an exception. I happened to (secretly) really love this one person, but I will never pursue it no matter what. What I am wondering about is, our sages (of blessed memory) said that in heaven everyone will be married to the one he truly loves, and nothing is prohibited. If I was patient for my whole life and kept on doing right deeds, then am I able to end up with that person in heaven? Even though it's homosexual?

Comment: can you provide a source for the idea that, "our sages (of blessed memory) said that in heaven everyone will be married to the one he truly loves, and nothing is prohibited", please.

Comment: In heaven even if couples are together in some way, it's also quite reasonable that they'd spend all day learning Torah or something, not having sex. I see no reason to think there is sex in heaven, as there is no procreation.

Comment: Rambam on chelek intro explained that corporal feeling are not relevant in heaven

Answer (score 3):

Nobody really knows for sure. Just be patient, don't lose hope, and sooner or later you'll find out. Hopefully later than sooner. I admire your self control.

Comment: Nobody knows for sure is an answer.

Comment: "nobody knows forsure " is really not am answer bevause that could be said to anything that relates to the future or after death,since no one can prove their theroy of what happens,but in Rabbanic literature there are concepts that are mentioned which one who belives in the Oral Torah will take as fact

Comment: @sam `but in Rabbanic literature there are concepts that are mentioned which one who belives in the Oral Torah will take as fact` The traditional belief in the Oral Torah [does not include every statement of the Sages](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351), so invoking belief in the Oral Law, does not alone prove the fact status of those statements. It is important to note that Hazal themselves, or at least one of them, asked rhetorically (Makkot 23b) "who rose to heaven and returned to tell" regarding claims about the otherwise unknowable.

Comment: @sam In a similar vein, note Rambam Hilkhot Melakhim 12:2 who emphasizes that various statements in Hazal about the Messianic Age are not based on Tradition, and in reality no one really knows exactly what will happen, and we will find out in due time.

Answer (score -2):

Not really a halachic point more a kaballistic one none-the-less I would say no for one simple reason in Judaism love is the unification of one half of a soul (the female) with their opposite and other half (male). According to Judaism you can't possibly by definition be truly in love with that person. I know that sucks to hear sorry.

Comment: Whether or not there is a kabbalistic concept commonly translated as and slightly analogous to love seems wholly irrelevant to the question and to the existance of the ops genuine emotions

Comment: The question was will one be with the one they truly love and I was answer that according to jewdisim one cannot be in love with some one of the same sex I was not commenting on the validity of this persons feelings

Comment: "according to jewdisim one cannot be in love with some one of the same sex" This is false. You haven't demonstrated that. You just referenced a kabbalistic concept which is commonly translated as and slightly analogous to "love". Completely irrelevant.

Comment: It is not at all irrelevant in fact it is all that is relevant

Comment: You aren't talking about the love that she is talking about. Do you not get that? You are talking about Kabbalistically how souls merge, while she is talking about a genuine emotional connection and commitment of caring and trust. What you are talking about is irrelevant, even if you use the word "love" in translating the technical Hebrew. Please keep your meaningless and mindless semantic mumbo jumbo to yourself. If you feel like spouting random Kabbalistic word games all over the internet, do it somewhere where you don't make someone who may not understand your misapplication feel terrible.