# Looking for a commentary, possibly in Mas. Nazir

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, commentaries, rashi, maseches-nazir

Connected to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82595/the-snake-slept-with-chavah) question.

In the discussion of the relationship between the Nachash and Chava, as related in Masechet Avoda Zara, 22b, the Chidushei Agadot [summarizes](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.22b.11?lang=bi&with=Chidushei%20Agadot&lang2=en) opinions about the connection between the two:

> מפרש"י פרק חבית כשנתן לה עצה לאכול מן העץ בא עליה דכתיב הנחש השיאני לשון נשואין עכ"ל ובנזיר הוסיף ביאור והיינו דקאמר לנחש כי עשית זאת איזה מעשה עשה אלא שבא על חוה כו' עכ"ל ע"ש

He cites Rashi from Mas. Shabbat 146a, that the snake gave Chava an idea, and then the possible connection between hisi'ani and n'su'in

The C"A then (it seems) he says that in Masechet Nazir, the explanation is continued and includes a more explicit statement about physical relations. It seems (to my simple reading) that he is attributing this also to Rashi, but the Rashi that I found (Nazir 23b) reads only

> בשעה שבא נחש וכו' '

and doesn't go any further (and I don't see other commentaries on the words which fill in what the claimed additions are).

Does anyone know of a fuller text of Rashi, or of another commentator, who says what the Chidushei Agadot claims is there, or can anyone help me understand the C"A in a different way?[2](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.22b.11?lang=bi&with=Chidushei%20Agadot&lang2=en)

Comment: what is according to you the claimed additions?

Comment: whatever is said that points to this "דקאמר לנחש כי עשית זאת איזה מעשה עשה אלא שבא על חוה" -- I looked for rashi on the next pasuk (asita zot) and saw nothing useful, and this pasuk is not referenced in Nazir

Comment: Oftentimes oz vahadar will add in sources, check there

Comment: BTW, since there's more than one Chidushei Agados (there's a sefer of the same name containing the Maharal's explanations), might be good to edit in that you're referring to Maharsha.

Comment: @Meir I'm using the text that I linked to through sefaria -- I don't know what they are choosing to label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in נוסחת הריב"ן on the side of the page in Nazir there, near the end of note Vov (referenced within the text of the Rashi). Here's what it looks like in the Vilna Shas, with the relevant parts highlighted:

[image]