# Origin of אין משיבין על ההגדה

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, midrash, literalism

What is the original source for the phrase: "אין משיבין על ההגדה" (or: "אין משיבין באגדה", "אין משיבין על דברי אגדה" etc. - which I believe is generally used to mean that it is inappropriate to derive a legal argument from a superficial/literal interpretation of a midrashic allegory)?

Comment: http://app.shaanan.ac.il/shnaton/13/7.pdf

Comment: Where did you see the expression? Why do you think it means that? What research have you done?

Answer (score 2):

This expression has various permutations: אין סומכין, אין משיבין, אין שואלין and על הדרש, על האגדה, etc. It goes back to at least the Geonim. For example, [Rav Hai Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hai_Gaon), cited by the Sefer HaEshkol (Hilkhot Sefer Torah) writes (as I cite in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53351/8775) relevant post):

> הגדה ומדרש אף על פי שכתובין בתלמוד אם לא יכוונו ואם ישתבשו אין לסמוך עליהם, כי כללינו הוא **אין סומכין על ההגדה**...ומה שלא נקבע בתלמוד אין אנו צריכין לכל כך, אלא מעיינין בו אם נכון הוא ויפה, דורשין אותו ומלמדין אותו, ואם לאו אין אנו משגיחין עליו.
>
> Haggada and Midrash--even if they are written in the Talmud, if they do not make sense, do not rely "lismokh" on them. For our principle is, we do not rely on hagada...And that which is not established in the Talmud, we do not need all this [to try and explain it, where possible]. Rather, we study it: if it is correct and good, we explicate and teach it. If not, we do not pay attention to it.

Even earlier Rav Sa'adya wrote (Otsar HaGeonim Hagigah p. 65) regarding the Seder Olam's views on dating Biblical events:

> זהו אגדה ו**אין סומכין על דברי אגדה**
>
> This is an aggada, and we do not rely on words of aggada.

Significantly, there is no indication whatsoever that the principle means that legal conclusions cannot be drawn from aggadot, as the context of Rassag is not halakhic! Furthermore, Rassag gives no indication that he means that the aggada may have esoteric meaning, and indeed as it is simply a question of the date that an event occurred.

In a similar vein, [R. Meir Halevi Abulafiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Abulafia) (cited there) writes:

> הגאונים רבינו סעדיה ורבנו האי ז"ל...והם אמרו **אין סומכין** ו**אין מביאין ראיה מכל דברי אגדה**, ו**אין מקשין מדברי אגדה**
>
> The Geonim Rabbenu Sa'adya and Rabbenu Hai OBM...And they said that we
>   neither rely on, nor bring proof from, nor ask on the basis of aggada.

Regarding the exact permutation you mention of אין משיבין, rather than אין מקשין, it is found in the [Mahzor Vitry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simhah_ben_Samuel_of_Vitry#The_Vitry_Machzor) (428), and in the writing of [Ramban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) (Yevamot 61b).

The context in the Mahzor Vitry regards the age of Bilam and divergent Midrashim about this, and the context of Ramban is the rejection of the Midrashic claim that Rivkah was three years old when she encountered Eliezer.

It is clear from the Mahzor Vitry, just as the expression is used by the Geonim, that this doesn't mean that we don't learn halakha from aggada, since the context is entirely non-halakhic. Nor is there any indication whatsoever that the principle relates to the issue of literal or non-literal interpretation of aggada. If anything his usage indicates that the reason that one cannot ask on the basis of aggada is that aggada is not absolute and is subject to diverse views.

Similarly, the context of Ramban fits the usage of the Geonim and provides no evidence that the problem with aggada is in its utility for halakha, nor that there is a problem with literal interpretation in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud Yerushalmi ([Peah 2:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40734&st=&pgnum=149)) states that we do not derive laws from aggadah:

> ר"ז בשם שמואל אין למידין לא מן ההלכות **ולא מן ההגדות** ולא מן התוספתות
>   אלא מן התלמוד

[R. Moses Margalit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Margolies) in his commentary [there](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40734&st=&pgnum=149) explains that this is because only Talmud has been subjected to the thorough process of clarification and analysis:

> אין למדין. הלכה למעשה דבר מן דבר ולא מן ההלכות שהוזכר בהן הלכה למ"מ
>   אין למדין מהלכה זו לדמות לדבר אחר כמוה **ולא ממה שהוזכר באגדות** ולא
>   מן התוספתות אלא מן התלמוד לפי שהאמוראים שבתלמוד הן הן שביררו הלכה
>   למעשה מתוך פלפולם ומתוך סברא שלהם ולפיכך אע"פ שלפעמים הוזכר במשנה
>   ובברייתא הלכה כר' פלוני אין סומכין על זה כ"א דוקא על הלכה שבגמרא

[R. Samuel Hanagid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ibn_Naghrillah) states very clearly (Mavo Hatalmud) that we can only derive from aggadah things that make sense:

> והגדה הוא כל פי' שיבא בתלמוד על שום ענין שלא יהיה מצוה זו היא הגדה
>   ואין לך ללמוד ממנה אלא מה שיעלה על הדעת

[R. David Ibn Zimra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) writes ([Shu"t Radbaz 2:647](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1952&pgnum=229)) that the Yerushalmi's statement is limited to where the source is not in consonance with our accepted principles:

> ואם הוא מסכים לכללים אשר בידינו למדין

[R. Jacob Ettlinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Ettlinger) similarly argues ([Shu"t Binyan Tzion # 173](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=591&pgnum=147)) that the Yerushalmi is only applicable when the aggada is contradicted by the Gemara:

> אכן גם מזה אין השגה דכבר כתב בקול הרמ"ז שם דמה שאין למדין ממדרש היינו
>   אם שיש בגמרא היפך המדרש אבל כשאין בגמרא סתירה למה לא נלמוד מן המדרש

This Yerushalmi is also discussed by [R. Menashe Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menashe_Klein) in a couple of places (Shu"t Mishneh Halachos [5:164](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1877&pgnum=225) and [10:203](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1882&st=&pgnum=313&hilite=)). He cites many earlier sources that discuss this, and he mentions an idea that aggadah is unreliable for halacha because it might have been written simply to contain "secrets", and thus lacks the precision of halachic statements:

> כיון דלא נכתבו הלכה למעשה ואולי רק להסתיר בהם סודות התורה כתבום ולא
>   דקדקו בזה שיהיה המעשה להלכה כיון דהעיקר להם בזה להסתיר סודות